# How to check if a specific Key combination and mouse left button is held down using pyautogui?

Tags: python, keyboard-events, mouselistener, pyautogui

I want to capture a part of the screen using a specific combo of mouse and keyboard.

I got the function for capturing screen, all i need is some way to react to a combination of mouse and keyboard eg:Ctrl+Shift+mouse-drag over specific area.

for the mouse drag over a specific area i need to do something like,check if Ctrl+Shift are held down and then record the coordinates of mouse as soon as it's clicked (the user begins to click and drag the area) and the coordinates when the click is released(the user completes selecting the area)...i need those four coordinates for my screen capture function

Here is some relevant incomplete code.I just need the function for on_press() to accomplish my goal

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput.mouse import Listener

def on_press(key):
    #Here i want to do the listening stuff and recording the mousepositions

def on_release(key):
   if key == Key.ctrl_l:
      if key == Key.shift:
         return False
   if key == Key.shift:
      if key == Key.ctrl_l:
         return False

with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

#x is the list which contains the relevant recorded coordinates
x=[top_left_x,top_left_y,bottom_right_x,bottom_right_y]

screen = grab_screen(region=(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]))

cv2.imshow('window',screen)
```

Please help me...if you are interested in the grabscreen function code
here it is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api

def grab_screen(region=None):

    hwin = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()

    if region:
            left,top,x2,y2 = region
            width = x2 - left + 1
            height = y2 - top + 1
    else:
        width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
        height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
        left = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
        top = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)

    hwindc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwin)
    srcdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwindc)
    memdc = srcdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    bmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcdc, width, height)
    memdc.SelectObject(bmp)
    memdc.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), srcdc, (left, top), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    signedIntsArray = bmp.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
    img.shape = (height,width,4)

    srcdc.DeleteDC()
    memdc.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwin, hwindc)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(bmp.GetHandle())

    return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
```

Comment: I'm open to other approaches of solving this problem too

Answer (score -1):

This should help. The `COMBINATION` list is the list of keys in the combination.

```
from pynput import keyboard

# The key combination to check
COMBINATION = {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.Key.alt, keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('x')}

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()

def on_press(key):
    if key in COMBINATION:
        current.add(key)
        if all(k in current for k in COMBINATION):
            print('All modifiers active!')
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        listener.stop()


def on_release(key):
    try:
        current.remove(key)
    except KeyError:
        pass


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

It works but if one of the modifier keys is pressed before the listener is started, it has to be released and pressed again for the program to detect it.

Comment: I also need to add mouse left click as one of the modifier keys.can u add that too?

Comment: for some reason the code doesn't recognise the 'ctrl' button when it's pressed...thus the if condition is never satisfied,same case with the 'alt' button but 'shift' and 'x' were recognised...i found this by printing the set current everytime a key is pressed

Comment: And you changed the list to the keys you wanted and pressed them in the order and it didn't work?

Comment: Yes and a no...I deleted the alt key and shift key from the combinations list from the code you gave and tried the exact same code,didn't work,...it didn't even work even when I run your exact code....